# Bootstrap datetimepicker first click fires onChange event?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

when I click and open the calender of bootstrap datetimepicker for the first time it will fires dp.change event. I need to avoid that. can someone help please ?

```
$('#dtpYear').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY',
        viewMode: "years"
    }).on('keypress paste', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

$('#dtpYear').off('dp.change').on('dp.change', function () {
        initAll();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have set a default value using below code

```
$('#dtpYearText').val(new Date().getFullYear());
```

then I changed it like below and problem solved

```
$('#dtpYear').data('DateTimePicker').date(moment(new Date()).format('YYYY'));
```